# Azure search sorting in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I want to implement custom search post.
I get results from azure search index as the exact documents are not returned for eg ; If I search for "Johnson" some records start with Johnson and some are not.

```
DocumentSearchResult<T> searchResponse = new DocumentSearchResult<T>();
searchResponse = indexClient.Documents.Search<T>(q, searchParams);
```

How do i sort the data from `searchReponse`?

Comment: What are your searchParams?

Comment: This is my searchParams= $count=true&facet=recordType&highlight=customerName,contactName&highlightPreTag=%3Cmark%3E&highlightPostTag=%3C%2Fmark%3E&queryType=simple&scoringParameter=custparam-'Customers'&scoringParameter=contactparam-'Contacts'&scoringProfile=boostCustomer&searchMode=any&$skip=0&$top=50}

Answer (score 0):

Another option, you could use Term Boosting:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt589323.aspx

or Score Profiles: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26706.what-are-scoring-profiles-in-azure-search.aspx

Comment: Hi, term boosting not working for me since its giving preference to scores and I want to override the scores and have a custom sort.

Comment: what about sorting with Linq?

Comment: How to do sorintg with Linq post azure search results.

Comment: @harshu288 searchResponse.Results.OrderBy(x=>x.FieldName)